# Android App that saves/retrieves data from a cloud server

Tags: android

I'm planning an Android application that allows users to fill out a form and save it to a server as a file. The app is also designed to show forms others have filled out and submitted to this server and allow the user to download and view them.

Frankly though, I'm not sure where to begin. I'm experienced with making client-side Android apps, but I've never done much work with servers and cloud storage. I've considered several options, such as setting up a Dropbox account to store and retrieve the data. I also have a spare computer I'd be willing to make into a dedicated server, I'd just need to know how to set it up as such and the methods I can use to access the server for saving and downloading files. Ideally I'd like to go with this method, as it ensures all files the App works with are on my own personal network.

If anyone could give me a head start on how to achieve this I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Saving on the cloud usually means the data is distributed over the network instead of it being stored on the server. But it doesn't sound anything different from writing a standard client-server app from the 'client' side; server-side will just communicate with other servers to keep the data consistent.

try a simple client-server combo first and then upgrade the server to it's 'cloud' version ;)

Comment: I suppose that's the case. When a user submits a form or votes on one (users will be able to vote up/down other forms similar to reddit), it saves this information to the server. When a user wants to see a list of all submitted forms, it downloads them from the server to the user's phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on Parse.com to store some data in the cloud without coding a single code line on server side...

Implementation is very easy.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic! I think I'll go with Parse. Even if 1GB isn't enough space, 1 cent for every extra gig is ridiculously cheap. Thanks!